# bitcoin HTTP request failed: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: 14.04, bitcoin

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu (I'm running 14.04) and I installed this [bitcoin wallet](http://postimg.org/image/4cx4wt6mj/) and I followed [these](http://www.return1.at/bitcoin-miner-ubuntu/) steps.

But I get the following error message:

```
HTTP request failed: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds
```

*How should I proceed?*